# .html end of URl affected to SEO?

Tags: php, posts, permalinks, seo

I want to convert PHP website into WordPress. So, I want to know there are a .html at end of the URL when WordPress permalink is not ended with .html. So, is it affected to SEO?

Answer (score 1):

If you currently have `/path/to/site.html` and change it to `/path/to/site`, this will affect SEO, as search engines think they know the url (the former).

However, there are solutions to this. You can either keep the `.html` at the end of the URL (there should be no problem to use a WordPress permalink with .html in the end), or if you want to clean up your URLs, you need to redirect from one to the other ([use 301 redirects](http://www.morevisibility.com/blogs/seo/when-and-why-to-use-301-or-302-redirects.html)).

There is extensive material on how redirects work ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)), if you only want the .html to disappear (and rest of the URL stays the same), something like this could already work in an .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(*.)\.html$ $1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Otherwise, you'd need a more complex structure which depends on your specific current situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin name '.html on PAGE', which will convert all pages to `.html` page. If you use this plugin you might also need to change in permalink to `/%postname%.html`